# Current Method to Mount /tmp in 22.04 and Newer with noexec

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab, tmp

I've read various other questions and answers and all of the guidance for mounting or changing the mount options for `/tmp` involve `/etc/fstab` or `/etc/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/tmp.mount`. However, I have looked on Ubuntu 22.04 and `fstab` has no entry for `/tmp` and the other file does not exist. I looked in `/etc/systemd/system` for any files that look like they would be similar to no avail.

What configuration on 22.04 controls the mounting of `/tmp` and how would I add `noexec` to the options?

Answer (score 1):

Create a systemd mount file.

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount
[Unit]
Description=Temporary Directory /tmp
Documentation=https://systemd.io/TEMPORARY_DIRECTORIES
Documentation=man:file-hierarchy(7)
Documentation=https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=!/tmp
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target
After=swap.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/tmp
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777,strictatime,nosuid,nodev,size=50%%,nr_inodes=1m,noexec

[Install]
WantedBy=local-fs.target
EOF
```

Enable the mount

```
systemctl enable tmp.mount
```

There is a sample mount file located at `/usr/share/systemd/tmp.mount`.  I am simply copying it and adding `noexec` to the mount options.

Comment: I don't think you need to create a whole unit. You could probably get away with just using an override file `/etc/systemd/system/tmp.mount.d/override.conf` and just have the `[Mount]` section with the `Options` line.

Comment: The unit must be created because the sample unit is in `/usr/share/systemd`.  That is not a path that systemd uses to find units.  Here is a more thorough answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/722500/439421

Comment: Ah, yes, Ubuntu's not using that unit by default. In that case I'd guess the recommendation there to use `/etc/fstab` directly would still be preferred to this method.